# In linux, stdin, stdout, stderr means open file descriptor?

Tags: linux

I have some question about stdio of linux system.
I know that fd 0, fd 1, fd 2 each refer stdin, stdout, stderr.
Does stdin, stdout, stderr means open file descriptor?

If i redirect it like 2>&1, what happen to relation between file descriptor and open file descriptor?

Comment: Yes, stdin, stdout and sterr generally refer to open file descriptors. Of course code can be written to close any file descriptor. So it depends on the context what those terms actually refer to but most of the time they would be open/valid fds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small C program `fd.c` that uses `stdout` and `stderr` to print a message to the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    fprintf(stdout,"message for stdout\n");
    /* fflush(stdout); */
    fprintf(stderr,"message for stderr\n");
    /* fflush(stderr); */

    return 0;
}
```

To compile: `gcc -o fd fd.c`

Open a terminal and test run:

```sh
./fd
./fd > /tmp/output.log
./fd > /tmp/stdout.log 2>/tmp/stderr.log
./fd > /tmp/all.log 2>&1
```

Examine each output file. If they look out of sequence, uncomment the `fflush` statements.

Nothing happens to their relations, they remain as they are as before. The `0,1,2` descriptors are always open by default.